# Как сделать backup/restore базы MSSQL программно

Tags: c#, sql-server

Как можно сделать backup/restore базы данных MSSQL программно на C#?
Пользователь выбирает место сохранения (например, флешку) и база сохраняется.

Так

```
public void BackupDB()
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
    dlg.FileName = String.Format("DataBase_{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".bak";
    dlg.Filter = "Базы данных (*.bak)|*.bak|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_сonnectionString))
        {
            var query = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE MYDB TO DISK='{0}'", filename);
            using (var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

не получается.

Пробовал вместо полного пути подставлять только имя файла. Тогда бэкап создается в папке по умолчанию, наподобие `C:\SQLDB\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\` (в данном случае сервер - локальный).

Но как программно наиболее простым способом можно узнать этот путь (имея в наличии строку подключения)? И можно ли из этой папки перемещать файлы на ту же флешку?

Comment: Если планируется, что сервер будет не локальным - то только через приложение. Всмысле, сначала бэкап на сервере, потом его передача через ваше приложение куда укажет пользователь. Ну и удаление бэкапа с сервера, чтобы место не занимал.

Comment: SqlExpress обычный (не SqlExpress LocalDB)?

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае задача не решается, потому что администратор сервера баз данных определяет - имеете вы доступ к бэкапам или не имеете. Он может закрыть учетной записи SQL Server'а доступ к каким либо компьютерам, кроме самого сервера, и закрыть вам доступ ко всем папкам на этом сервере, для примера.

В частных случаях есть два варианта:

- Вам необходимо обеспечить доступ учетке SQL Server'а к вашей флешке, либо подключив ее локально к серверу, либо использовав имеющую доступ к сети учетку SQL Server'а и дав этой учетке доступ к своему устройству через сеть, обращаясь при этом, понятно, по сетевому имени, например \\COMPUTER\E$\MyBackupDirectory.
- Делать бэкап в локальную директорию на сервере баз данных в папку, доступную вашему приложению по сети (такую папку вы предварительно должны создать и настроить) и после выполнения бэкапа копировать его на флешку.

Если же отвечать на вопрос, как узнать этот путь (хотя, на самом деле, вам это не нужно), то получить его можно следующим запросом (при наличии нужных прав, понятно):

```
EXEC  master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',N'BackupDirectory'
```

Comment: вроде речь в вопросе была про локально установленный sql express?

Comment: @teran, по фразе "в данном случае сервер - локальный" я сделал вывод, что локальный сервер приведен в качестве примера.